# Mixed Content issue is driving me nuts

Tags: wordpress, mixed-content

Ok, so I've never been as confused as I am right now, so I really hope that someone can help me. I've recently installed a certificate on my website as well as installed the SSL plugins on Wordpress, however some of my pages are still not entirely secure. The error message says: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.dk/en/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://website.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/8/bg02.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS"

So, the problem here is that when I go look for that image in that directory under file manager, it's not there. I'm sure it has been there before, but I probably deleted it. My guess is that this issue occurs because something is still linking to that file. Where and how do I fix this?

NB! website.dk is not the website that I own. Due to restrictions from my employer, I'm not allowed to link anyone to our website at this very moment.

Comment: I would suggest you to Google your problem first. There you will find many tutorials that can explain you the things more clearly.

Comment: Trust me, I have googled this issue for hours, and I can't find anyone who has the same problem as me. The problem is that I can't just delete this file or rename it, because it's simply not there.

Comment: If you can find a similar problem, you're more than welcome to share it with me! It seems like there is something linking to something that is not existing. How that can be fixed, that's what I have no clue about.

Comment: In desperate cases like this i download the backup with all files and sql output into a directory and then search the string, or the filename in the whole folder with a suitable tool. for example TextPad (Edit->Find in Files)
https://www.textpad.com/download/

Comment: I've done that now, and those files are not there.